# python define variable difference before/after main block

Tags: python, variables, scope

what is the difference in python  when defining variable before or after main block? See variable "lock" in following code examples.

The following code works:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Lock

lock=Lock()

def single_process(num):
    lock.acquire()
    print(num)    
    lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=single_process, args=(123,)) 
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=single_process, args=(456,)) 

    p1.start() 
    p2.start()

    p1.join()    
    p2.join()
```

but following code does not work, saying lock is not defined:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Lock

def single_process(num):
    lock.acquire()
    print(num)    
    lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    lock=Lock()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=single_process, args=(123,)) 
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=single_process, args=(456,)) 

    p1.start() 
    p2.start()

    p1.join()    
    p2.join()
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to provide Python version and OS info with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the lock to the child processes, via the args.

---

**Explanation:**

I think you are running this on Windows. Either way, you should not expect all the variables you declare or values you set in parent process to be available in child processes automatically. See [this](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) for synchronisation (locks) and and [this](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for different ways of sharing data to child processes.

That said, both code snippets you posted are running for me on my system (Linux). The difference in Linux is, the [fork()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) system call is used to start new processes. Fork makes a copy of the calling process. So it inherits the state of the main process.

On [Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows), there is no fork() system call. So when a child is created, the module is reloaded in the child processes without the `__name__` set to `__main__` (otherwise it would lead to a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) in your code). So in your first snippet, the `lock` variable will be set be set in the child process also, because it is not inside `if __name__ == "__main__"`. But in your second snippet, the lock variable will not be set, because it is inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.